# Where can I practice my Python and Bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, python

I wanted to practice my bash scripting skills and python skills and wanted a good book or a site where I can practice and get excellent skills please. Any recommendations please.

Answer (score 3):

For python at least I recomend "Learn Python The Hard way", by Zed Shaw. Freely available online. Good stuff. Not sure if posting a link here is technically advertising... Here goes. [Free Book](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many. I can suggest two for python:

- codecademy: to learn syntax and get a basic understanding of the langauge
- newcoder.io: some projects to go further